# Unit test in NestJS with Jest with MongoDB

Tags: mongoose, jestjs, mongoose-schema, nestjs

I am implementing unit test in the framework NestJS with Jest. When I launch the tests, this error occurs:

[image]

My test file is this:

[image]

My app.module.ts is:

[image]

My usuario.controller.ts is:

[image]

My **usuario.service.ts** is:

[image]

My usuario.squema.ts is:

[image]

I think the problem is the injection of the model (@InjectModel of user.service.ts) of nestjs at the time of solving the dependency injection in the test file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And post your code inline rather than as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of `mongoose` you're using, but, as the error is stating, `mongoose.Schema` is probably not a constructor.

From the [Getting Started](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) of mongoose v5.0.16 :

`var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});`